# Why is this simple threading output correct

Tags: c#, multithreading

Going through this [article](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

```
class ThreadTest
{
  static void Main()
  {
    Thread t = new Thread (WriteY);          // Kick off a new thread
    t.Start();                               // running WriteY()

    // Simultaneously, do something on the main thread.
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) Console.Write ("x");
  }

  static void WriteY()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) Console.Write ("y");
  }
}
```

Produces:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
yyyyyyyyyyyyyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
...
```

Why isn't it producing results like this?:

```
xyxyxyxyxyxxyyxyxxxyyxyxyx....
```

"A thread is an independent execution path, able to run **simultaneously** with other threads."

The above doesn't exactly look simultaneous to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two threads *cannot* run concurrently because they both do nothing but repeatedly access the same resource. When one thread is running, the other thread is almost certainly waiting for the console and cannot run. Test with two threads that do something other than exclusively access precisely the same unsharable resource.

You and me can do errands concurrently. But if the only errands you and I need to do require the same car, then we'll wind up taking turns. And you won't just do one errand and then bring the car back so I can do one errand. That would be ridiculous and we'd spend all our time bringing the car back. You'd do a few errands, then I'd do a few.

Comment: Fair enough, but with that logic it seems x would print to 1000, then y would print to 1000. Here it's printing each letter a dozen or so times then giving control to the other thread. Is that by design?

Comment: The scheduler picks the most efficient pattern given its constraints. Letting one thread go to 1,000 would be more efficient from a resource utilization standpoint but it would cause problems for applications that need more 'fairness' among threads. The design is a trade-off.

Comment: Some OSes will let one thread use out its timeslice. This will tend to be the design for OSes that have small timeslices. Some OSes will let the blocked thread gradually gain "dynamic priority" until it can pre-empt the other thread as soon as it's ready-to-run. The behavior may also be different on single-core versus multi-core and may also be different depending on whether other cores are idle or not. It's surprisingly complicated and filled with tuning and heuristics to optimize both latency and throughput.

Answer (score 3):

Depending upon the **[scehduling policy](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/doc/genprogc/threads_sched.htm)** each thread get scehduled to run for a certain amount of time(Thread Quantum) Since you have tight loops, The time slice assigned to each of your threads is enough to output more than one print and that is why you see the behavior of multiple prints from each thread.

Comment: So what you're saying is each thread has a maximum time it can keep control of a resource before giving control to another thread? If so, is this controlled by C#, or is it much lower level?

Comment: @Nick: That is exactly how it is(the actual process is more complex though involving preemption and non-preemption). It is controlled by the scheduler but whichever library or platform you use will provide you means of configuring these parameters when you spawn your threads.Check the link.

Answer (score 0):

When somebody says "threads run simultaneously", he is abstracting on how the system appears to work, rather than how it actually works.

It's just like hearing somebody tell you that the computer generates random numbers. It doesn't really, but it appears to, and that's a good enough way to work (except for when it isn't).

The operating system or runtime environment continually gives each thread a slice of CPU time to run in. How big the slice of CPU time you get is a "Known Unknown".

In your example, the threads happened to be allocated enough CPU to output around 16 characters. Run it under a slightly different set of circumstances and you might get a different result. Such is the nature of multithreaded programming.

Comment: Computers really do generate random numbers. It's only theoretical computers that have to fake it. Real world computers have access to real world randomness. (For example, if you capture the TSC when a network packet arrives, the result will be truly random because it depends on the frequency aliasing between two quartz oscillators which depends on microscopic zone temperature variations in their crystals, which is a truly random quantum effect.)